# android calling a method when closing an app or restarting device

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, ondestroy

I am trying to have my app save the time of a chronometer when the app is either manually closed or the device is restarted but my code does not seem to work.

What am I doing wrong? the onCreate works if I assign the the below method to a button. I just cant get it to fire automatically when the app closes.

```
protected void onDestroy() {
        final Chronometer chrono9 = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);



        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putLong("time", chrono9.getBase());
        editor.commit();
        super.onDestroy();

    }




protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mydialog);





    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        Chronometer chrono9 = (Chronometer)findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);
        chrono9.setBase(settings.getLong("time",11));
```

Comment: Could you post the part where you get the "time" from the shared preferences?

Comment: check how you read the value in sharedPreferances. Also onDestory() is to do final cleanup , so do your preference save in onPause/onStop.

Comment: I added my on create that gets the time from saved preferences. This part DOES work when I manually store the time in saved preferences with a button. I just cant get it to store it automatically when the app closes.

Answer (score 2):

are you implementing this into a service...??? What you have to do is implement a service that is going to start its run when the user close the app, and you will have to implement a broadcast receiver so you will know when the phone gets rebooted...

this is going to be a class...

```
public class StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    context.startService(startServiceIntent);
}
```

and this goes in your manifest...!!

```
<receiver android:name="com.solmoviles.tmp.StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

any further questions I'll be more than happy to help!

Comment: Thanks for your help. This actually isnt a service its just for a simple chronometer that I have running in my main layout. I can get it to work if I store the time with a button I just need a way to make the method that stores it to the saved preferences to fire automatically on app close.

Answer (score 0):

What I wound up doing in my particular case is storing the chronometer in shared pref in the same method that I start it with.

Now when I restart my app the time continues ticking and has not reset from where it was when I closed the app.

In my method that starts the chronometer:

```
...
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putLong("time", chrono9.getBase());
        editor.commit();

...
```

in my on create :

```
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        Chronometer chrono9 = (Chronometer)findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);
        chrono9.setBase(settings.getLong("time",11));
```

...

```
        chrono1 = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);

...
        chrono1.start();
```